# How does the sequence of tags like action-state and decision-state influence a Spring Webflow?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a generic understanding on how the Spring actions work and the format of a x-webflow.xml file.

Nevertheless I lived under the false impression that the sequence in which elements like `<action-state>, <decision-state> and <view-state>` are being written in the webflow.xml configuration file is not defining the "actual" flow, and the flow is resulting from the logic in which those elements reference eachother.

Nevertheless I have been shown that the order in which you write the elements in the config file is important. Could you help me with some example of clarification on how the order of the elements affects the webflow (like if you put this element before that one the flow is x, if you switch them the flow is y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for the very first state in the file does the sequence matter. That defines the starting state. All the others are only referenced by other states, so their order doesn't strictly matter.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/defining-flows.html#flow-element

> The first state defined becomes the flow's starting point.

IMO, it's a good *convention* to roughly order them in the order they're used, but you can never fully do that if you have more than one path through the flow.

Similarly, it's a good *convention*, but not *necessary* to put all `<end-state>` definitions at the end of the file.